# keeping positive in a covid-19 winter

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "positive" best used in the headline? At first glance, I naturally linked it with covid-19 - positive in testing? Sad, you've become a new case of the nasty virus. But then I read the content and found that it meant "optimistic". But the word "positive" is indeed too sensitive in 2020, because the link betwwen "positive" and "covid-19" is overwhelming in the global health crisis and is better to avoid using it in narrow space.

What is your opinion?

> The Scandinavian secrets to **keeping positive in a covid-19 winter**
> Lockdown restrictions in winter might seem something to dread, but we can combat this by embracing the mindset of people used to long, dark winters, says health psychologist Kari Leibowitz

> Source: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg24833112-500-the-scandinavian-secrets-to-keeping-positive-in-a-covid-19-winter/#ixzz6fx3UwdpU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a phrase, "keeping positive" unambiguously means "to remain optimistic." If it said "testing positive", that would be about virus testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential ambiguity with positive. Consider

> Q Did anything positive happen to you this week?
> A Yes, I had a COVID-19 test

In this case we do not know whether the test turned out positive or the outcome was viewed in a positive light. However in the example you quote I do not think a native speaker would see it as anything other than meaning *optimistic*.